# java compile time error, due to downgrade from jdk7 to jdk6

Tags: jvm, java

Initially my code was build/compiled using open-jdk7.

But due to some constraints I now have to use open-jdk6 only. So, when I tried compiling my code using jdk6 I got the following error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
 javaapplication1/JavaApplication1 : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

OS used: ubuntu 11.10

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you try to compile it (command line/build tool)? Are there any jars used for this?

Comment: compiled it using Netbeans build tool. Nope, no jars used.

Comment: *"when I tried compiling my code using jdk6 I got the following error: ... UnsupportedClassVersionError:"*  That is a run-time error, not a compile time error.  Try to get these things right.   Programming is a technical business, accuracy is important.

Comment: yes, thanks for pointing out my mistake. Will see to it that it wont happen again..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a result of depending on some other classes (libraries/jars) that is compiled on different version of JDK (1.7 in this case).

Make sure that you use the 1.6 compiled version of the jars/libraries.

Comment: *"Make sure that you use the 1.6 compiled version of the jars/libraries."* Best achieved using the [cross-compilation options of `javac`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#crosscomp-options)

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have the code? Could you recompile the raw code with JDK-6?

Comment: *"recompile the raw code with JDK-6?"*  Unnecessary (at least the 'JDK-6' part), see Ahmad's answer.